# Why is there no exception when adding null to a string?

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

Why doesnt this throw an exception dont understand, obj is null

```
object obj = null;
Console.WriteLine("Hello World " + obj);
```

Comment: There's probably a default to string implementation for null references. What's the console output?

Comment: For future reference, you'll probably get a better response if you use meaningful question titles. Of course you are getting answers, but in general, people prefer to look at questions that say what they are...

Answer (score 21):

This compiles to

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Hello World ", obj));
```

The [`String.Concat` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx) ignores `null` parameters.

It's defined like this: (From the .Net reference source)

```
    public static String Concat(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        if (arg0==null) {
            arg0 = String.Empty; 
        }

        if (arg1==null) { 
            arg1 = String.Empty;
        } 
        return Concat(arg0.ToString(), arg1.ToString());
    }
```

I don't know why it doesn't simply return `arg1.ToString()` if `arg0==null`.

The `String.Concat(string, string)` method is defined like this:

```
    public static String Concat(String str0, String str1) { 
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(str0)) { 
            if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) {
                return String.Empty; 
            }
            return str1;
        }

        if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) {
            return str0; 
        } 

        int str0Length = str0.Length; 

        String result = FastAllocateString(str0Length + str1.Length);

        FillStringChecked(result, 0,        str0); 
        FillStringChecked(result, str0Length, str1);

        return result; 
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't return arg1.ToString() if arg0==null, because arg1 may also be null, which would cause an exception.  The double checking is handled in the string version of ConCat, so all we're losing is one method invocation.

Comment: @James: It could do an extra `null` check and `return String.Empty` immediately.  We're also losing extra `String.Empty` calls.  (Although they're probably inlined by the JITter)

Answer (score 3):

Passing a `null` parameter to a method is not necessarily going to throw an exception; that's up to the implementation of the method (and in that case you'd probably see an `ArgumentNullException`).

Attempting to access a *member** of a `null` object** is what will **always** throw a `NullReferenceException`, guaranteed***.

So...

### May or may not throw an exception

```
object obj = null;
SomeMethod(obj); // passing as parameter
```

### Will *definitely* throw an exception

```
object obj = null;
int hashCode = obj.GetHashCode(); // calling instance method
```

In the case of the code in question, the parameter you are passing to `Console.WriteLine` is actually the result of a compiled call to `string.Concat`, which allows `null` values to be passed as parameters and essentially ignores them -- as [SLaks already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312504/why-is-there-no-exception-when-adding-null-to-a-string/3312509#3312509).

---

<sub>*Extension methods are a different matter; they can be called on "null" parameters; but since these only present the *illusion* of acting like instance methods, this rule does not apply to them. In fact, extension methods are after all just static methods. If you call one "on" a `null` value, you are effectively passing `null` as a parameter.</sub>

<sub>**Here I am not including `Nullable<T>` values with `HasValue == false`; though these might conveniently be treated as `null` in many cases, this is just for syntactical convenience: they are no more `null` than any other value type can ever be `null`.</sub>

<sub>***I'm talking about C# here. As SLaks points out in a comment, this is not a rule of the CLI itself. But all instance method calls in C# are compiled to `callvirt` instructions in IL, which *will* throw an exception if the instance is `null`.</sub>

Comment: Not always. `Int? obj = null; obj.GetHashCode()` returns `0`.

Comment: @SLaks: Well, you could say that. But you and I both know that the `null` in `int? obj = null;` is not really `null`.

Comment: Nitpick: Although it's impossible in C#, a `call` instruction can also call a method on a null reference without throwing an exception (unless the method uses `this`)

Comment: Just to add a further wrinkle, extension methods allow expressions that look like a method call on an instance to actually be passing a parameter to a static method and therefore not necessarily throw an exception.

Comment: @SLaks: Right -- I seem to remember reading that that's why all method calls in C# are compiled to `callvirt` instructions in IL, right? So that calling methods on `null` objects will always throw a `NullReferenceException`? Anyway, we are talking about C# here after all...

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Yes yes, but extension methods do not count as member access! Gah, I need to fix up this answer, it seems ;)

Comment: @Dan Tao, software engineers are always looking for corner cases :)

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Look at how atrocious my answer looks now with all those horrible footnotes. Damn you and your nitpicking!

Comment: Could be worse, the footnotes could have their own footnotes.

Comment: One final nitpick that Mark Gravell pointed out elsewhere is that if you call .GetType() on a `Nullable<T>` with HasValue=false, it actually _will_ throw a NullReferenceException, due to the fact that GetType() can't be overridden and the nullable will box to null before the call.

Answer (score 1):

Because that would be annoying. For most pruposes there is no semantic difference between an empty and a null string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue where this might occur in a real application, you could always check for null before displaying the text. Then, you could display an alternate text, or nothing.

Comment: On a side note, the null-coalescing operator `??` is extremely handy for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: @Dan Bryant Nice enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

Because they implemented String.IsNullOrEmpty and left it to us to figure out how to use it.