# string = string + int: What's behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, string, casting, integer

In C# you can implicitly concatenate a string and let's say, an integer:

```
string sth = "something" + 0;
```

My questions are:

1. Why, by assuming the fact that you can implicitly concatenate a string and an int, C# disallows initializing strings like this:

   ```
   string sth = 0; // Error: Cannot convert source type 'int' to target type 'string'
   ```
2. How C# casts 0 as string. Is it `0.ToString()` or `(string)0` or something else?
3. How to find an answer of the previous question?

Comment: I particularly like how you ask "How to find an answer of the previous question?"

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It compiles to a call to [`String.Concat(object, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx), like this:

```
string sth = String.Concat("something", 0);
```

(Note that this particular line will actually be optimized away by the compiler)

This method is defined as follows:  (Taken from the .Net Reference Source)

```
    public static String Concat(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        if (arg0==null) {
            arg0 = String.Empty; 
        }

        if (arg1==null) { 
            arg1 = String.Empty;
        } 
        return Concat(arg0.ToString(), arg1.ToString());
    }
```

(This calls `String.Concat(string, string)`)

---

To discover this, you can use `ildasm`, or Reflector (in IL or in C# with no optimizations) to see what the `+` line compiles to.

Comment: SLaks is correct, but to expound on the OP's questions:
1) "+" is an overloaded operator between string and object
2) Yes, .ToString() is ultimately called
3) Reflector

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312504/why-is-there-no-exception-when-adding-null-to-a-string/3312509#3312509).

Comment: It may be useful to throw up some IL to save a bit of time for those lazy programmers... *(All of us...)*

Comment: It seems that the compiler doesn't optimize this away; there's an interesting debate about this on JetBrains: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/266160

Answer (score 24):

This is specified in section 7.8.4 of the C# 4 spec:

> For an operation of the form `x + y`,
>   binary operator overload resolution
>   (§7.3.4) is applied to select a
>   specific operator implementation. The
>   operands are converted to the
>   parameter types of the selected
>   operator, and the type of the result
>   is the return type of the operator.
>
> The predefined addition operators are
>   listed below. For numeric and
>   enumeration types, the predefined
>   addition operators compute the sum of
>   the two operands. When one or both
>   operands are of type string, the
>   predefined addition operators
>   concatenate the string representation
>   of the operands.

The last sentence is the most relevant one to this situation.

Then later:

> String concatenation
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
>
> string operator +(string x, object y);
>
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> These overloads of the binary +
>   operator perform string concatenation.
>   If an operand of string concatenation
>   is null, an empty string is
>   substituted. Otherwise, any non-string
>   argument is converted to its string
>   representation by invoking the virtual
>   `ToString` method inherited from type
>   object. If `ToString` returns null, an
>   empty string is substituted.

That specifies how the integer is converted into a string.

And the result:

> The result of the string concatenation
>   operator is a string that consists of
>   the characters of the left operand
>   followed by the characters of the
>   right operand. The string
>   concatenation operator never returns a
>   null value.

The actual means of performing concatenation is implementation-specific, but as noted in other answers, the MS implementation uses `string.Concat`.

Comment: Does `"abc" + 123` result in the `123` being boxed? Would `"abc" + 123.ToString()` be minimally more efficient?

Comment: @andleer: It's implementation-specific, but yes, it does... so in theory, `123.ToString()` would be more efficient, but it's possible that the JIT is aware of this pattern.

Comment: Crude benchmark with 25 million iterations shows `ToString()` to be about 7% quicker. Framework 4.5.1 and like I said, crude (but measurable).

Comment: has this feature been introduced in c# 4  ?  I mean was it not there in prior versions of c# ?

Comment: @Dhanajay: What, the string conversion of non strings for concatenation? No, it's been there forever.