# Does streams use Boxing and unboxing when print array of int values

Tags: java, java-stream

if i run this line of code :

```
Arrays.stream(new int[] {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}).forEach(x->System.out.print(x+ " " ));
```

Is there any boxing or unboxign happens on the values?

Comment: You can use the the method boxed() to box it to an Integer. Try this example:.List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(new int[] {2, 4, 6, 8, 10})
                .sorted()
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no auto-boxing / auto-unboxing happening. You invoke `IntStream stream(int[] array)` which deals with `int[]` and `int` without having any `Integer` involved. The `forEach` gets an `IntConsumer` which deals with `int` only. And the string concatenation does not appear to involve boxing either ([String Concatenation and Autoboxing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445064/string-concatenation-and-autoboxing-in-java)) since `StringBuilder.append(int)` is used.