# C# concatenation strings while compiling

Tags: c#, .net, string, compiler-construction, concatenation

Please help understand this behavior. When I use this:

```
bool a1 = (object)("string" + 1) == ("string" + 1);
```

The result is `false`

But when I use this

```
bool a2 = (object)("string" + "1") == ("string" + "1");
```

The result is `true`

So, why `a1 != a2`?

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but I know you shouldn't be checking string quality using "==" anyways. object1.equals(object2) is the way to go with that, at least to my understanding. I didn't post this as an answer though because it probably doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398604/string-string-int-whats-behind-the-scene-c

Comment: @Ricky Mutschlechner: AFAIK the operator '==' == '.equals'. ;-)

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner In C#, `==` is fine for comparing strings, as long as they're both treated as strings - this is just a funky case when you're dealing with strings that are cast as objects. But `"string" + 1 == "string1"` still returns true. It's Java that you really need to use `equals`. The biggest reason I avoid `Equals` in .NET is that you have to check the first one for null every time, to avoid NullReferenceException, where using `==` works fine for comparing nulls.

Comment: @FabianBigler good to know! I'm definitely a Java user who has just recently started with C#, but this is definitely something I'll keep in mind. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner No problem. Make sure you read Joe Enos comment as well (it's very informing and adds some nice thoughts)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Casting to `object` forces a reference equality comparison.

In the first case two different `string` objects are generated at runtime. Since they are different instances the result is false.

In the second case the compiler notices that `"string" + "1"` is always going to be `"string1"` and interns the string and uses the same reference in both places. Since it is the same string reference, the result is true.

Comment: @OP Just to add on, you should always compare strings with String.Equals

Comment: @Mataniko No, you should just make sure that your variables are of a compile time type string if you use `operator ==`.  Use `string.Equals` only if one or more of the objects isn't statically typed to `string` (which should really be quite rare).

Comment: @Servy a more common use of `string.equals` is when you want to use different comparison systems. `Ordinal` and `OrdinalIgnoreCase` are things I tend to use a lot, especially because they're much faster than standard `==`.

Answer (score 19):

There are two important things going on here:

First, The expression `"string" + 1` is evaluated at run-time while `"string" + "1"` is evaluated at compile-time.

Secondly, you're using reference comparison. The run-time generated strings actually reference different object while the compile-time generated strings reference the same object, so the first expression is `false` and the second expression is `true`.

If you're interested, the generated IL is:

```
// bool a1 = (object)("string" + 1) == ("string" + 1);
// bool a2 = (object)("string" + "1") == ("string" + "1");

IL_0000:  ldstr       "string"
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0006:  box         System.Int32
IL_000B:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_0010:  ldstr       "string"
IL_0015:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0016:  box         System.Int32
IL_001B:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_0020:  ceq         
IL_0022:  stloc.0     // a1
IL_0023:  ldstr       "string1"
IL_0028:  ldstr       "string1"
IL_002D:  ceq         
IL_002F:  stloc.1     // a2
```

Comment: Neat.  Care to mention how one would view IL like this?