# A want to add a data from mysql table with the sum of a gridview (row), but it shows -use of unassigned local variable 'a' error in vs05, c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview

```
void opt_gridview1()
{
    string myConnection = "datasource= localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from bs.buffer where   type='buffer'", myConn);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myConn.Open();
    string a;

    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    a = myReader.GetString(1);
    myConn.Close();

    double sum_petrol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
          sum_petrol += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

    }

     this.label8.Text = String.Format("{0:n2}", sum_petrol+a);
}
```

Comment: change `string a` to `string a = string.empty`

Answer (score 2):

With proper indentation you could see that there is a path, in your code, in which the variable `a` is not initialized.
The compiler cannot know, at compile time, if your `myReader.Read()` returns true or false and notice this fact blocking your compilation until you fix the error.

```
....
string a;

myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
    a = myReader.GetString(1);

 ...

 this.label8.Text = String.Format("{0:n2}", sum_petrol+a);
```

You could easily fix it with initializing the variable `a` with an empty string

```
string a = string.Empty;
```

However, a part from this, the final line where you add a double with a string has baffled me.
It seems to be working, probably thanks to some not very known rule of string.Format, but I would try to change that. It the field at index 1 returned by the reader is a numeric value I suggest to use a variable of the proper type.

Comment: It is the C# `+` operator (not `String.Format()`) that enables concatenation of a string and another type. [As described in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398604/string-string-int-whats-behind-the-scene-c), the C# spec dictates that when one operand is a string the plus (+) operator automatically converts the other operand to a string.

Comment: Thanks, however not a thing you can rely on. What happens here? `string a = "1";double b = 1.2;string.Format("{0:n2}", b + a);` -> 1.21

Comment: Can't rely on the spec?  In that example, I would expect that the operation `b + a` results in the string `1.21` which would then cause a `FormatException` to be thrown since the argument is not numeric.

Comment: Not my intention to say that. Just the concationation of a double with a string and then pass it as string to a numeric format string let me think that the poster want a sum and not a string. However that code doesn't throw any exception. At least in a snippet run under LinqPAD- It remains unclear what the poster would expect from this operation

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the `a` variable in the `while` loop. But there is no guarantee your code will enter the loop.
You can initialize it when you create the variable:

```
string a = string.Empty;
```

or

```
string a = null;
```