# how to load image into c# code directly from folder without using openfiledialog

Tags: c#, string, image, path

any help for this problem:

```
     for(int i=1;i<28;i++)
     {  
     Bitmap image = new Bitmap("Image\\" + i + ".jpg");
     }
```

i want to load images like this directly from ( **Image**) folder into solution Explorer and then process it but I'm having problem.
could anyone help??

when i run the code it throws *Argument Exception* and says "Parameter is not valid. "

I think there is some problem with the path but I don't know the right way

Comment: Please explain what problem exactly you're encountering.

Comment: If you want help in regards to an error you also need to include which error it is that you are getting. in this case I take it the compilöe error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify the full file path `C:\Images\...`

```
for(int i=1;i<28;i++)
{  
  Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Image\" + i + ".jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is mostly because of a variable type problem:

```
  for(int i=1;i<28;i++)
     {  
     Bitmap image = new Bitmap("Image\\" + i + ".jpg");
     }
```

The problem here is that you have string + int + string.

Thus you would need to transform i into a string which can be done by usint ToString thus: i.ToString().

```
  for(int i=1;i<28;i++)
     {  
     Bitmap image = new Bitmap("Image\\" + i.ToString() + ".jpg");
     }
```

That should work then. That is if you have the images in an Image  folder which is a subfolder of the execution folder.

Comment: `str + int + str` is ok (equivalent to `String.Concat()`)

Comment: thanks for response but it is still giving that problem :(

Comment: @AlexK. sure there? str + int doesn't work.  But str + int + str is translated into String.Concat by the compiler?

Comment: `str + int` is actually legal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398604/string-string-int-whats-behind-the-scenes