# How are strings terminated in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null-terminated

This program throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

```
string name = "Naveen";
int c = 0;
while( name[ c ] != '\0' ) {
    c++;
}
Console.WriteLine("Length of string " + name + " is: " + c);
```

Why is it so?
If strings are not null-terminated. How strings are getting handled in C#?
How can I get the length without using `string.Length` property?
I'm confused here.!

Comment: why dont you want to use `string.Length`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the length property to get length??

Comment: I want to terminate a given string where '\0' is included in the string.? eg: "Nav\0een".

Comment: "Why is it so?" Because null-terminating strings is a bad idea... it means that strings can't contain embedded null characters, and you can't find the length of the string without iterating over it...

Comment: Well in what way is that string null-terminated? That's a string of length 7, not a string of length 3. You can easily *find* the part before the first null character and take that substring if you want, but you should really explain more about *why* you want to do this, as it's a reasonably odd requirement.

Comment: in .net String is a class [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx). It is not null terminate char[] as in c++.

Comment: It is null terminated. But the wrapper around it handles ALMOST EVERYTHING

Comment: @all Thanks for your effort to make me understand :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# does not use NUL terminated strings as C and C++ does.  You must use the `Length` property of the string.

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of string " + name + " is: " + name.Length.ToString());
```

or by using formatters

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of string '{0}' is {1}.", name, name.Length);
```

Comment: `.ToString()` in the 1st row is not required http://stackoverflow.com/a/3398653/1315444

Comment: Don't forget `$"Length of string #{name} is #{name.Length}"` :)

Comment: @fubo It's not required but it's more explicit that way. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static void Main()
 {
     unsafe
     {
         var s = "Naveen";
         fixed (char* cp = s)
         {
             for (int i = 0; cp[i] != '\0'; i++)
             {
                 Console.Write(cp[i]);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

// prints Naveen

Comment: Can you explain this? It's not compiling in my Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to use /unsafe compiler option.

Comment: FYI, In VS -> Project's Properties -> build tab -> Check allow unsafe code.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ string is stored in is a `char` array AFAIR without intelligence and behaviour. Therefore, to indicate that such array ends somewhere, one must have added \0 at the end.

On the other hand, in C#, string is a container (a class with properties and methods); as a side note you can assign null to its instantiated object. You don't need to add anything to it to indicate where it ends. The container controlls everything for you. As such, it also has iterator (or enumerator in C# i think). That means you can use `foreach` and `LINQ` expressions to iterate over it.

Having said that, you could use a simple counter in a code similar to this to get a length of a string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LengthOfString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "abcde\0\0\0";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine("s.Length = " + s.Length);
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Here I count the number of characters in s
            // using LINQ
            int counter = 0;
            s.ToList()
                .ForEach(ch => {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", (int)ch));
                    counter++;
                });
            Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine("LINQ: Length = " + counter);
            Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine();

            //Or you could just use foreach for this
            counter = 0;
            foreach (int ch in s)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", (int)ch));
                counter++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine("foreach: Length = " + counter);

            Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a character at an index which is not available according to `name` length. You may solve it this way:

```
string name = "Naveen";    
int c = 0;
while (c < name.Length)
{
    c++;
}
```

> However there is no need to count the length of a string in c# this
>   way. You can try simply `name.Length`

**EDIT:** based on what @NaveenKumarV provide in comments if you want to check for `\0` characters then as others said you may try `ToCharArray` method. Here is the code:

```
var result = name.ToCharArray().TakeWhile(i => i != '\0').ToList();
```

Comment: What a pointless method... it's just the same as `name.Length`

Comment: Your method does NOT do that. `ToCharArray` will get you closer.

Comment: The constraint is shown in the conditional expression at while loop. It tells inested of checking for a null character he should compare the length with the index.

Comment: `ToCharArray` `char != '\0'`

Comment: @Hossein Thanks for alternate solution: var result = name.ToCharArray().TakeWhile(i => i != '\0');

Comment: @NaveenKumarV glad to be helpful