# Why does this string get cast to an Object in the DLL?

Tags: c#, .net

I was comparing 2 DLL's, which I don't do often, and I was confused when I saw this line:

```
myObj.ErrorString = (string) (object) num + (object) " file(s) failed to import. Run the Import Report for more information.";
```

`num` is an `int`, which is being cast to an `object` then to a `string`. My hard-coded string is being cast to an `object` in order to be "added to" the `num` variable which has been converted to a string.

Why does the compiler "add" a `string` and an `object`? Wouldn't it make more sense for it to be `(string)(object)num + (string)"some text";` ?

Comment: look at how string.concat works; that might explain it for you; also this is a good example why you need to explicitly convert certain things to avoid boxing etc

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama how would that explain anything, it doesn't make sense. There's no point in boxing around like this, in the end it's just myObj.ErrorString = num + " file(s)....";

Comment: You're thinking like a human and not a computer :D

Comment: There's no boxing in this casting; both `String` and `Object` are reference types. How are you "comparing" these DLLs? I'm guessing that you're using some sort of disassembler, right? This looks like an artifact of the disassembler, not the compiler. Try looking at the MSIL instead.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I apologize. It's true, that's a boxing cast. OK then, that's simple. I'll write an answer now.

Comment: @Vilx- you're saying an int being made an object isn't a boxing?

Comment: @Vilx- I used dotPeek to decompile the two and then just copy-pasted the contents of the two classes from my 2 DLL's into Winmerge

Comment: Exactly. I think it's an artifact of the decompiler. Check the MSIL. That cast (`int` -> `object` -> `string`) isn't even valid. Try it - you'll get an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score -2):

The call to `a + b` gets changed by the compiler to a call to [`String.Concat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx). The only override of that method which has parameters of an acceptable type is [`String.Concat(Object, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft(v=vs.110).aspx). So both arguments need to be cast to `Object` before they can be passed to the method.

For more info look a the article linked to by [sstan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4955425/sstan) - [string = string + int: What's behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398604/string-string-int-whats-behind-the-scenes)

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama - And why not?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama - Why not answer a question even if it is a (borderline) duplicate?