# How to fetch data from a dynamically created textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a follow up question for [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669075/c-sharp-winforms-adding-two-textbox-automatically).

However in this question, I created such a `Control` so whenever I click on the button, two `TextBox`es will appear (Indefinite count/click) in a row. Whenever I input again a value, they will do the addition and put the result in the third `TextBox` of their row.

```
   private void buttonNewRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 1;
            DateTimePicker date = new DateTimePicker();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<DateTimePicker>().ToList().Count;
            date.Location = new Point(0, 15 * count);
            date.Size = new Size(91, 20);
            panel1.Controls.Add(date);

           //Textbox 1
            TextBox textboxTranspo = new TextBox();
            textboxTranspo.Location = new Point(576, 45 * count);
            textboxTranspo.Size = new Size(81, 20);
            panel1.Controls.Add(textboxTranspo);

            //Textbox 2
            TextBox textboxDaily = new TextBox();
            textboxDaily.Location = new Point(663, 45 * count);
            textboxDaily.Size = new Size(81, 20);
            panel1.Controls.Add(textboxDaily);

            //Textbox 1 + Textbox 2 result
            TextBox textboxTotal = new TextBox();
            textboxTotal.Location = new Point(772, 45 * count);
            textboxTotal.Size = new Size(100, 20);
            panel1.Controls.Add(textboxTotal);
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think, You should try grid control.

Comment: Set the control's Name property then use <container>.Controls("name") to access the control.

Comment: The normal solution of this approach is to define a `UserControl`. You can add your logic to the user control and you just add it to the your panel programmatically.

Comment: `FlowLayoutPanel` or `DataGridView` controls instead of `Panel` can make it a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

I will address my comment above as an answer.

First you have to define a `UserControl` and named it whatever you like but let us name it `Uc1`.

In the designer drag the `datetimepicker` and the 3 `textboxes` to the `Uc1`. Supposed we name the control `dt1` for `datetimepicker` and `txtTranspo` for `textbox1` and `txtDaily` for `textbox2` and `txtTotal` for the last one. And since we need to compute the value of `txtTranspo` and `txtDaily` i want to add 1 `button` named `btnCompute` for computation logic for simplicity sake.

then inside the `Uc1`

```
class Uc1
{

    public Uc1() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.wireEvents();
    }


    // This will handle all controls events for well organized form sakes.
    private void wireEvents()
    {
        this.btnCompute.Click += OnBtnComputeEvent;
    }


    private void OnBtnComputeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // i used int since i do not know exactly how to do this.
        int transpo = Int32.Parse(this.txtTranspo.Text);
        int daily = Int32.Parse(this.txtDaily.Text);
        double total = ((transpo + daily) / 100 * 100) // <--- this is just a random computation.

        this.txtTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:c}", total); // this will format the total to a currency.
    }

}
```

Then build the solution. or click the combination of `Ctrl + Shift + B`. After this the `Uc1` will appear to your `toolbox` as a new control.

Then you can simply do this to your own logic.

```
private void buttonNewRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Uc1 c = new Uc1();
        c.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        c.BringToFront();

        this.panel.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

You are good to go.

Comment: There is one thing. `'int' does not contain a definition for 'parseInt'` that is the error im receiving.

Comment: Hello, I manage to debug some error so far the `string.format` should be `string.Format` but there is one last error which is `btnTotal`. It said that it does not contain a definition for `btnTotal`

Comment: Oh, i just mistype it is the same txtTotal let me update

Comment: Wait a minute, how can I fetch the variable from the user control and add them up to the main form? So that I can get all the value of the txtTotal and add them up to a different textbox in the main form.

Comment: @Noobster what do you mean? you want to get ALL the txtTotal value of each usercontrol? or the SUM of ALL the txtTotal in each usercontrol?

Comment: The SUM of ALL the txtTotal that is produce in my usercontrol. I'm afraid I don't understand why you said `each`.

Comment: because you can add multiple user control in your panel

Comment: Oh yes, the sum of all the txtTotal, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handlers like this:

```
private void buttonNewRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTimePicker date = new DateTimePicker();
    int count = panel1.Controls.OfType<DateTimePicker>().ToList().Count;
    date.Location = new Point(0, 15 * count);
    date.Size = new Size(91, 20);
    panel1.Controls.Add(date);

    //Textbox 1
    TextBox textboxTranspo = new TextBox();
    textboxTranspo.Location = new Point(576, 45 * count);
    textboxTranspo.Size = new Size(81, 20);
    panel1.Controls.Add(textboxTranspo);

    //Textbox 2
    TextBox textboxDaily = new TextBox();
    textboxDaily.Location = new Point(663, 45 * count);
    textboxDaily.Size = new Size(81, 20);
    panel1.Controls.Add(textboxDaily);

    //Textbox 1 + Textbox 2 result
    TextBox textboxTotal = new TextBox();
    textboxTotal.Location = new Point(772, 45 * count);
    textboxTotal.Size = new Size(100, 20);
    panel1.Controls.Add(textboxTotal);

    EventHandler textChanged = (o, e) => {
        int intTranspo, intDaily;
        if (int.TryParse(textboxTranspo.Text, out intTranspo)
         && int.TryParse(textboxDaily.Text, out intDaily))
            textboxTotal.Text = (intTranspo + intDaily).ToString();
    };
    textboxTranspo.TextChanged += textChanged;
    textboxDaily.TextChanged += textChanged;
}
```

Comment: How can I get all the textboxTotal and add them all up to a different textbox?

Comment: good way is to add them to a `List<TextBox>` when created, or a less reliable way something like `panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => t.Left == 772).Select(t => int.Parse(t.Text)).Sum()`