# what does ' "" ' mean in ' "" + ex ' in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I always use it but don't understand what it's doing.

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "" + ex;

    }
    return "Name : " + result;
```

When I hover over it it says "Represents text as a series of Unicode Characters." I know it has something to do with last line of the code but why is it ' "" ' before.

I've seen [string = string + int: What's behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398604/string-string-int-whats-behind-the-scenes) that talks about similar looking case of `"" + 1` (or general "String + object"). In my case `ex` is clearly not an `int` so this is not duplicate of that question.

Comment: It will call the `ToString` method of `Exception` and append it to the empty string.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question so it can be re-opened as new and unique? It feels that you already know that `""` is string constant, so code you have should be rewritten as following [MCVE]: `string result = "" + new Exception();`. You also read documentation from the answers I've linked as duplicate - so you know what `string +` exist... Unfortnately at this point I don't understand what other information is needed (but I spent some time in C# - so too many things are obvious to me)

Comment: (I've also edited "This has nothing to do with `int`" into sentence that includes link to duplicate - please try to do similar edits in future if you need to say "not a duplicate". Otherwise  if question re-opened "not an int" would look completely out of place without context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`""` is an empty string. `"" + ex` is a anti-pattern to force `ex` to be converted to a string, giving the message of the exception.

So basically, instead of creating two strings and concatenating them (leading to creating a third string), this would have been better:

```
return ex?.ToString();
```

And since it is an exception handler, and you know `ex` can't be null, this would do too:

```
return ex.ToString();
```

Comment: Out of interest, when would `ex` ever be `null` in this context? Would that ever reach the catch site?

Comment: No, but you know, copy pasting this code will prevent one more vote-as-duplicate on a NRE.

Comment: It may be good idea to note that returning success and failure in indistinguishable ways may not be the best coding practice either... even with good name [stringly typed code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

Answer (score 5):

quote marks just denote a string literal. Here, `"" + ex` is just bad code - that creates a string by concatenating `ex` with the empty string (`""`). It is equivalent to:

```
return ex?.ToString();
```

except it will return `""` even if `ex` is null... so perhaps:

```
return ex == null ? "" : ex.ToString();
```

Comment: Why would your exception in a catch ever be null? Isn't he just being lazy and not wanting to write to string?

Comment: @johnny5 it shouldn't be; I'm talking about what the precise meaning of `"" + foo` is, not the semantics of exceptions.

Comment: You could also write it as `ex?.ToString() ?? ""`.

Comment: @Kyle you could; I kinda made the assumption that somebody asking what `"" + ex` meant would also be confused by `?.` and `??`

Answer (score 3):

It's idiomatic in languages like C# and Java. Prefixing with any string literal (and `""` has the most benign effect) puts the binary addition operator `+` into a sort of concatenating "string mode", therefore forcing the calling of `ToString` on the exception object.

Rather cute really, although `return ex.ToString();` is probably less obtuse.