# ABOUT C# BRACKETS

Tags: c#

I am giving an example in the photo I put, if we do not put the parentheses when we write 5 and 10, it says 510. What is the reason for this?[enter image description here][1]

```
Console.Writeline("Enter the numbers you want to sum in order:");
int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("the sum of the numbers you entered : " + num1 + num2);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: You should put the code within the text (copy paste the actual code) instead of linking an image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string = string + int: What's behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398604/string-string-int-whats-behind-the-scenes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the string you have before, what you write is equivalent to :

```
"the sum of the numbers you entered is :" + 5 + 10;
```

which is the sum of a string with 2 integers, what happens when you add a number to a string is that ToString() is implicitely called in the number (making it text, it's no longer a number) so this code is also equivalent to

```
"the sum of the numbers you entered is :" + "5" + "10";
```

If you want the numbers added you need to add them together before the implicit conversion to the string happens so you could simply put the addition of the 2 numbers between parenthesis so they're taken into account before being added to the string (and converted to a larger string) :

```
"the sum of the numbers you entered is :" + (num1 + num2);
```